# unary operators in printf

Tags: c, printf, unary-operator

Can anyone explain me the output of the following. I tried to reason everything and can explain the later part where 'x' is assigned the value of the expression but cannot understand how the answer is different in a printf statement!!!

Different compilers might behave differently. It would be great if someone could explain this behavior for any compiler.

I am using gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.6.2 on openSUSE 12.1 (Asparagus) (i586)

code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
unsigned int x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x),x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x)||x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x||x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",++x||x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",x++||++x||x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x||x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
(x^=x);
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
(x^=x)||x++;
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
(x^=x)||x++||++x;
printf("x=%d\n",x);
x=0;
(x^=x)||x++||++x||x++;
printf("x=%d\n",x);

return 0;
}
```

output :

```
expr= 0 x=0
x=0
expr= 0 x=1
x=1
expr= 1 x=2
x=2
expr= 1 x=2
x=2
expr= 0 x=1
x=1
expr= 1 x=1
x=1
expr= 1 x=2
x=2
expr= 1 x=2
x=2
x=0
x=1
x=2
x=2
```

Thanks

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Please specify **which** of these you don't understand (better yet, just remove all the ones you do understand).

Comment: I'm continually amazed at the shear number of people who want to pre and post increment a variable between sequence points... why?

Comment: @EdS.: `||` is a sequence point.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Haha, how did I miss all of those? :D  Looks like David did too.

Comment: Yeah I just read `(x^x)||x++||++x||x++` and reacted on instinct.....

Comment: To the OP, give this link a read. http://susam.in/blog/sequence-points/

Comment: @oli: lets just say I am confused with the two scenarios: x=0;
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x||x++,x);
printf("x=%d\n",x); and x=0;
(x^=x)||x++||++x||x++;
printf("x=%d\n",x);

Comment: @shadyabhi: I understand the concern and I am not a fan of these little tricks. Though I am just curious how to approach these questions taking into consideration any one type of compiler, say gcc 4.6.2 (I am running opensuse 12.1, i586)

Comment: @user1170267 I wasn't informing you about the tricks. It's not my blog. I just found it useful. It explains the concept taking references from The Standard and book like K&R. So, just felt like sharing.

Comment: Is this one of those questions where you want to know what your particular compiler happens to be doing but don't care that the code will behave differently on other compilers?

Comment: @David: This code might be inconsistent on different compilers but there should be some higher level reasoning to the behavior. After all, compilers do follow same standards. When I saw this snippet of code, I was curious and tried different permutations, as you can see in the code, but I still do not get the difference in behavior of the same expression in a printf as opposed to an assignment.

Comment: Since you are asking about your specific compiler then you should say what it is in the question

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this forum. I will edit the question and take care of it the next time.

Answer (score 4):

You are invoking **unspecified behaviour**.

In an expression like `func(a,b)`, the C standard does not specify which argument should be evaluated first; the compiler is free to do either.

So now consider `func(x++,x)`; it is unspecified whether it is equivalent to this:

```
a = x++;
b = x;
func(a,b);
```

or this:

```
b = x;
a = x++;
func(a,b);
```

Comment: That is the reason why I also have a printf("%d\n",x) after each printf("expr=%d x=%d",'expr',x) just to confirm the same. Looks like the output is consistent.

Answer (score 3):

```
printf("expr= %d x=%d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x,x);
```

This function shows unspecified behavior. The order of evaluation between `(x^x)||x++||++x` and `x` is unspecified.

Most of the other `printf` calls in your program have the same issue.

> (C99, 6.5.2.2) "The order of evaluation of the function designator, the actual arguments, and
>   subexpressions within the actual arguments is unspecified, but there is a sequence point
>   before the actual call."

A program whose output depends on unspecified behavior is not a strictly conforming program (see C99, 4.p5).

Comment: IThat is the reason why I also have a printf("%d\n",x) after each printf("expr=%d x=%d",'expr',x) just to confirm the same. Looks like the output is consistent.

Comment: @user1170267 the output can be consistent with your compiler but as it is unspecified behavior it can be different with another version of the same compiler or even different with the same compiler but another day of the week.

Comment: lets say, I am just concerned with printf("expr= %d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x||x++) ..... and (x^=x)||x++||++x||x++) for the moment.

Comment: @user1170267 `printf("expr= %d\n",(x^x)||x++||++x||x++);` is not unspecified behavior and is strictly conforming.